# Use IF condition after making Select in SQL Database

Tags: java, sql, if-statement, authentication

I have a Login table on my system, and after the user logged in  I want to compare what level of access he has to see which one (s) module (s) of the system he can access.

**The user table has:**

- Id
- Name
- User
- Password

**The Access Level table has:**

- Id
- User
- Level of access to the system

  **A user can have N access levels ("operational", "financial", "administrator")**

I used this code:

```
public void Logar(){  

    String sql = "Select * from login where usuario_login = ? and senha_login = ?";  

    try{  

        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);   

        pst.setString(1, txtUsuario.getText());   
        pst.setString(2, txtSenha.getText());   

        rs = pst.executeQuery();   

        if(rs.next()){  

            FRMPrincipal frm = new FRMPrincipal();  
            frm.setVisible(true);  

            dispose(); 
        }  

        else{  

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário ou senha incorretos!");  
        }  
    }  

    catch(SQLException error){  

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);  
    }  
}
```

**I want to implement so that:** when the user logs me to capture the user ID and do a select on "Access Level" table to see what "access levels to the system" by that user has. Then I'll go to the home page of the system according to the filtering made access level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in one query only, using a join. Your SQL query becomes:

```
Select l.*, a.level from login l
left join access_level a on l.id = a.user
where l.usuario_login = ? and l.senha_login = ?
```

I'm assuming that the access level table is named `access_level`.

If a user can have several "access levels", then it is cleaner to have a second query to fetch the list of accesses:

```
select a.level from access_level where user = ?
```

Comment: And how am I going to compare the amount raised by the query?

Example:

If user has level access to the system = operational and financial he can access two system modules!

I need to capture the user's level of access to the system and then implement with IF condition.

Comment: ah yes, in that case, two queries will indeed be necessary.

Comment: OK, and how do I compare a result of a select with the IF condition?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem there. Just create a collection of the user's access authorisations, and use something like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object) to test for the current module access rights.

Comment: Managed to solve comparing the values of the ResultSet.

After the query I did: `String levelAcess = rs.getString ("levelAcess");

if (levelAcess.equal ("Administrator")) {

       // Code to execute Administrator form

}

else if (levelAcess.equals ("financial") && levelAcess.equals ("Administrator")) {

      // Code to execute Administrator and financial form

}`